# SOAP BODY Field in ESQL

Tags: soap, entity-sql

How to get Content-Transfer-Encoding="CDATA" in my soap body.
I have tried with DECLARE IDOC_BLOB BLOB
        A

```
SBITSTREAM(InputRoot.BLOB,InputRoot.Properties.Encoding,InputRoot.Properties.CodedCharSetId );
        DECLARE IDOC_CHAR CHAR
        CAST(IDOC_BLOB AS CHAR CCSID InputRoot.Properties.CodedCharSetId);
        SET Environment.Messagecontent = IDOC_CHAR;
        SET BODYoutref.message.(XMLNSC.Attribute)'Content-Transfer-Encoding' = "CDATA";
        SET BODYoutref.message.(XMLNSC.CDataField) = Environment.Messagecontent;
```

But I am not getting Content-Transfer-Encoding="CDATA" . Suggest some changes 
My requirement is

```
< soap:Body>
    <Message Content-Transfer-Encoding="CDATA"><![CDATA[{message}]]</Message>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Is how We should code to get proper result

```
DECLARE FILE NAMESPACE 'CDATA';
DECLARE IDOC_BLOB BLOB


ASBITSTREAM(InputRoot.BLOB,InputRoot.Properties.Encoding,InputRoot.Properties.CodedCharSetId );
        DECLARE IDOC_CHAR CHAR
        CAST(IDOC_BLOB AS CHAR CCSID InputRoot.Properties.CodedCharSetId); 
        SET BODYoutref.(XMLNSC.CDataField)Message = IDOC_CHAR;
        SET BODYoutref.Message.(XMLNSC.NamespaceDecl)"content-Transfer-Encodeing" = FILE;
```